# SQL: select items from one table only if in other table they have both columns with same value

Tags: plsql

I need some hints.. I got a tables which look like that:

| ID | ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | XXXX |
| 2 | YYYY |
| 3 | ZZZZ |

| ID | ID_2 | SUBITEM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | AA |
| 1 | 11 | BB |
| 2 | 12 | CC |
| 2 | 13 | DD |
| 3 | 14 | EE |
| 3 | 15 | FF |
| 3 | 16 | GG |

| ID_2 | value |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 13 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 |
| 16 | 0 |

I need to get all items where ALL sub-items are = 1.

for example XXXX should not be listed, because BB has value 0.

```
select distinct         
(table1.item)  
from table1,        
table2,        
table3 
where table1.id = table2.id        
and table2.id_2 = table3.id_2        
and table3.value = 1 
order by table1.item
```

my code gives me all items wherever 1 is a value

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: `select distinct

       (table1.item),

from table1,
       table2,
       table3
where table1.id = table2.id
       and table2.id_2 = table3.id_2
       and table3.value = 1
order by table1.item`

Answer (score 2):

I would use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT i.ID, i.ITEM
FROM items i
INNER JOIN subitems s ON s.ID = i.ID
INNER JOIN vals v ON v.ID_2 = s.ID_2
GROUP BY i.ID, i.ITEM
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN v.value != 1 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

The `COUNT` expression above will count 1 every time a value *other* than 1 appears for a given item.  A matching item, then, is one whose non 1 count is zero, meaning all values are equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Then zzzz shouldn't be in result set either, as GG has value 0.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  a (id, item) as
  3    (select 1, 'xxxx' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'yyyy' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'zzzz' from dual
  6    ),
  7  b (id, id_2, subitem) as
  8    (select 1, 10, 'aa' from dual union all
  9     select 1, 11, 'bb' from dual union all
 10     select 2, 12, 'cc' from dual union all
 11     select 2, 13, 'dd' from dual union all
 12     select 3, 14, 'ee' from dual union all
 13     select 3, 15, 'ff' from dual union all
 14     select 3, 16, 'gg' from dual
 15    ),
 16  c (id_2, value) as
 17    (select 10, 1 from dual union all
 18     select 11, 0 from dual union all
 19     select 12, 1 from dual union all
 20     select 13, 1 from dual union all
 21     select 14, 1 from dual union all
 22     select 15, 1 from dual union all
 23     select 16, 0 from dual
 24    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 25  select a.item
 26  from a join b on a.id = b.id
 27         join c on c.id_2 = b.id_2
 28  group by a.item
 29  having min(c.value) = max(c.value)
 30     and min(c.value) = 1;

ITEM
----
yyyy

SQL>
```

In other words: join all three tables. As `having` clause is to be used, group by the `item` column and set *conditions* (you said that all values must be 1).